# Structuring an application so that it is modular

Tags: php, model-view-controller, architecture, hmvc

I am attempting to achieve a solution for the following scenario:

I have an application that allows someone to manage their address book / list of clients. 
`(MODULE CLIENTS)`

Someone using this might then need a list of jobs that links to clients.
`(MODULE JOBS)`

Someone else might need a list of properties that links to clients and jobs.
`(MODULE PROPERTIES)`

Is there a way to make it so that you could literally:

drop the `CLIENTS` and `JOBS` modules in a fresh install and they could then communicate

drop the `CLIENTS`, `PROPERTIES` and `JOBS` modules in a fresh install and they could then communicate (client -> properties -> jobs per property OR clients -> jobs)

or even drop the `CLIENTS` and `PROPERTIES` modules in a fresh install with similar scenario as clients / jobs.

I know I would have to define relationships somewhere but I am trying to architect it so that I can do that either through standard relationship controllers (and where best to put them) or via a config file.

I am not a purist so I am quite happy to drop extra controllers in modules as and when but I just want to stream-line the process.

Or would it be better to produce 'filler' modules that bridge the gap and use them to construct the views instead??

I am also wondering how best to architect the views - the way I have it at the moment is to have a view and then 'pagelets' that are individual components of that view (tables, forms etc. - each one a pagelet) -> I just call the pagelets via Module::Run (if you are used to codeigniter -> basically the same as 'include') -> this is great but might not be the best system for the above scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Module Wiring**

Unless you are using a HMVC framework that can 'intelligently' handle this style of (module) linking you would need to 'configure' or 'wire' it in some way. Whilst I am unaware of any HMVC framework that can do that, I would imagine that if one did you would need to program your controllers to some form of 'interface' (term used loosely) so it knew how they all linked up.

Using a 'non-intelligent' framework, one would need to use either a global configuration file or module configuration files in some form (such as yaml, xml, php, etc) explaining the linking between modules. Again, I am unaware of such a HMVC framework.

All that said, it would be a great project to undertake and it would definitely move the HMVC framework world further along though I do suspect that doing so may loose some flexibility in the way you program your controllers primarily because of the language (parameters) each module would need to implement to talk or interface with another (controller).

**Filler Modules**

My preferred approach and that of other frameworks (MVC and HMVC) is to have a route matching up to a primary controller (your 'filler' module). Then that primary controller calls it's sub-controllers (modules) and if need-be sub-sub-controllers (more 'filler' modules), etc, gathering is data, populating it's views then working its way back up (and where necessary back down again) until the primary view can be populated.

I have created my own HMVC framework that does just that with my 'request' classes based off the [Kohana](https://kohanaframework.org/index) framework. This [TechPortal](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/) link describes how it works in a detailed yet understandable way.

**Views**

The architecture of your views (or 'pagelets') sounds correct. I call them panels. So, using **output buffering**:

1. The primary controller 'requests' a sub-controller (with any parameters passed to it if required) with the sub-controllers response set to a variable. Eg:

   ```
   // Create a new request to a controller.
   $request = RequestFactory::createRequest();
   $request->controller('modules/customers/customers/controllers/CustomersController@showAllAddEditDelete');
   $currentCustomers = $request->execute();
   ```
2. The sub-controller gathers any necessary data, renders it in the pagelet and returns it.

   ```
   // Instantiate the view object.
   $view = new View();

   // Instantiate the customers model.
   $customersModel = new CustomersModel();

   // Set the data.
   $view->data('customers', $customersModel->getCustomers(), false);

   // Set the template.
   $view->template('modules/customers/customers/views/show_add_edit_delete');

   return $view->render(false);
   ```
3. The primary controller then prepares its data and renders it's view.

   ```
   // Instantiate the view object.
   $view = new View();

   // Set the panels.
   $view->data('panel_1', $currentCustomers, false);

   // Set the panels layout.
   $view->partial('panels', 'views/html/secure/templates/panels/layout_2');

   // Set the template.
   $view->template('views/html/secure/templates/application.php');

   // Render the page.
   $view->render();
   ```

This process can go down as deep (nested) as you need it to.

I hope this helps.